# ajax submit button not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to display the comment content by fill in the password inputted in the comment form by the end-user but the ajax submit button is not working. Is their any conflict? 
Please help me to improve this code.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button").click(function() {
            var password = $("#search").val();
            if (password != "") {
                $("#result").html("<img alt="ajax search" src='ajax-loader.gif'/>");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "search.php",
                    data: "password=" + password,
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#result").html(data);
                        $("#search").val("");
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        $("#button").click(function(){
            search();
        });

        $('#search').keyup(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                search();
            } 
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
    <?php if(!$userdata->data->ID):?>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="password" id="search" placeholder="This is a secret question." />
            <input type="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
            <ul id="result"></ul>
        </form>
    <?php endif?>
</body>
```

Comment: where is the `search` function

Comment: you have a syntax error in `$("#result").html("<img alt="ajax search" src='ajax-loader.gif'/>");`, it should be `$("#result").html('<img alt="ajax search" src="ajax-loader.gif"/>');`

Comment: Are you getting console errors? If you use Chrome the javascript console has an option to log ajax requests.

Comment: search id and search() , code shows you are confused

Comment: try by making change within this `data:{password:password}`

Answer (score 0):

the same problem but i have solution

it's weird a little bit but
**the solution is to remove `type="button"`**
**and use `type="submit"`**